# How can I import part of LinPhone library for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, linphone, linphone-sdk

I want to import LinPhone library for receiving VoIP calls in my app.

This is my Pod-file:

```
platform :ios, '13.0'
source "https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/podspec.git"

target 'ClientApp' do
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'ReachabilitySwift'

    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

    pod 'SVGKit', :git => 'https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit.git', :branch => '3.x'

    pod 'linphone-sdk'
end
```

My app size before import LinPhone - 60 mb, after import - 240 mb. This is very unpleasant surprise.

When I opened [the gitlab link with source](https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/podspec.git) in browser, I saw this:

[image]

How can I import only linphone-sdk-novideo to reduce application size?

P.S.: "pod 'linphone-sdk-novideo'" - dont work.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

`pod 'linphone-sdk'`

with

`pod 'linphone-sdk-novideo'`

in your `podfile`

Comment: P.S.: "pod 'linphone-sdk-novideo'" - dont work. At least at the time the question was asked

Comment: This pod works now?

Comment: @alexbayker For me earlier versions are working but latest `linphone-sdk-novideo` and the `linphone-sdk` are not working. I am getting "multiple commands produce... error